# Windows defender won't finish scanning archives

Tags: windows, windows-10, archiving, windows-defender, rar

I recently run into an issue where Windows Defender wouldn't finish a full scan (it would scan files infinitely, reporting unrealistic number of files scanned). Now I think it's due to my RAR archives not being scanned correctly. When I run a custom scan, which should scan only one archive it behaves in the same way - doesn't finish and scans an infinite number of files, much more than there are in the archive.

I turned off archive scanning with a PowerShell command (`Set-MpPreference -DisableArchiveScanning 1`), run the full scan again and it completed successfully.

What might be the issue here? I've already run `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup`, `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth` and `SFC /SCANNOW`. I don't want to leave archive scanning turned off for security reasons.

Comment: Move the RAR files to another drive / USB drive so they are not on drive being scanned and scan again with Defender.

Comment: Where did these RAR files come from, and which application generated them? Windows Defender seems to fail to understand their format.

Comment: @John I moved an archive to another drive and windows defender scans it correctly. Do you know what might me a cause for this?

Comment: So Defender is working well. There must be some issue with the RAR files.  Try running Defender against just (only) the RAR files. Put them all in one folder to begin with and scan that. See what surfaces from this scan.

Comment: @John I just did some more testing and it seems that it's not a drive issue. I tried copying the same archive that was successfully scanned on the other drive (it was originally on my system drive) and copied it to another location on the system drive and scanned it. The scan completed successfully. So, it seems that it doesn't matter where the file is, but rather whether it was moved recently. I should also mention that I did a clean install of windows recently and moved all my files using an external drive.